# Changing label text from another class JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a test program that has a button in one tab and a label in another.  I want the button to add one to the label when pushed.  The problem I'm having is that the label does not change when the button is pushed.  How to I change label text from another class?

Here's the code:

Base

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane.TabClosingPolicy;

public class Base extends Application {
    
    // Create tabs and the tab pane
    private TabPane tabPane;
    private Tab testTab1;
    private Tab testTab2;
    
    // Create menus
    private Test1 test1 = new Test1();
    private Test2 test2 = new Test2();
    
    //Constructor
    public Base() {
        
        // Instantiate tabs
        testTab1 = new Tab();
        testTab2 = new Tab();
        
        // Instantiate tab pane
        tabPane = new TabPane();
    
        // Add the panes to the TabPane
        testTab1.setText("Button");
        testTab2.setText("Label");
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(testTab1, testTab2);
        
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 700, 500);
        testTab1.setContent(test1);
        testTab2.setContent(test2);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test program");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Test1

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Test1 extends Pane {
    
    Test2 test2 = new Test2();
    
    Button testBt = new Button();
    
    public Test1() {
        testBt = new Button("Change label");
        testBt.setLayoutX(50);
        testBt.setLayoutY(50);
        
        getChildren().add(testBt);
        
        testBt.setOnAction (new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle ( ActionEvent e) {
                int newTest = test2.getTest() + 1;
                test2.setTest(newTest);
                test2.setLabel(test2.getTest());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Test2

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class Test2 extends Pane {
    
    int test = 0;
    
    Label label = new Label("");
    
    public Test2() {
        
        label.setText("" + test);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30));
        label.setLayoutX(50);
        label.setLayoutY(50);
        
        getChildren().add(label);
        
    }
    
    public int getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    
    public void setTest(int newTest) {
        test = newTest;
    }
    
    public void setLabel(int newLabel) {
        label.setText("" + newLabel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a two separate instances of `Test2`, one in your `Base` class and the other in your `Test1` class.

The one in your `Base` class is the real one because that is the one that has been added to your testTab like so `testTab2.setContent(test2);`.

The first order of business is to remove this line `Test2 test2 = new Test2();` from the `Test1` class, because it only confuses the situation and does nothing.

The next order of business is to work out how to pass the current/correct instance of the `Test2` into the `Test1` class. There are lots of ways to do that, but here is one solution that edits the `Test1` class to include a `createEvent` method that lets us pass the correct reference of Test2 into the method:

```
public class Test1 extends Pane {
    
    //Delete or comment out the below line
    //Test2 test2 = new Test2();
    
    Button testBt = new Button();
    
    public Test1() {
        testBt = new Button("Change label");
        testBt.setLayoutX(50);
        testBt.setLayoutY(50);
        
        getChildren().add(testBt);
    }
    //New method
    public void createEvent(Test2 pane){
        testBt.setOnAction (new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle ( ActionEvent e) {
                //Here we can reference the pane object that was passed to the method
                int newTest = pane.getTest() + 1;
                pane.setTest(newTest);
                pane.setLabel(pane.getTest());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in the `Base` constructor we can simply use the following line to create the event:

```
//Constructor
public Base() {
    //Insert this new line that calls the `createEvent` method and passes the correct test2 object
    test1.createEvent(test2);
```

Now it should all work as intended, with the value of the label incrementing by 1 each time the button in Test1 is clicked

Comment: I made the suggested changes but Eclipse is not liking them.  Adding `test1.createEvent(test2);` to Base gives the following warnings:

 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
 - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
 - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
  MethodHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
  QualifiedName

Comment: There is also an error in the `pane.setLabel(test2.getTest());` line in Test1:  "test2 cannot be resolved"

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix both issues. You will need to put `test1.createEvent(test2);` inside the Base constructor (not directly in the class). and for the second issue replace `test2` with `pane`  on that line